# Подскажите бесплатные сервисы для локализации ПО

Tags: локализация

Имею небольшой Open Source проект на GitHub. На данный момент он содержит всего около 30 строк и своими силами переведён на английский и русский язык. Хочу добавить поддержку для других наиболее распространённых языков (французский, немецкий, испанский и т.д.). Система локализации самописная, основанная на ini-файлах.

Заинтересовал сервис https://crowdin.com/, но как оказалось он платный. Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть **бесплатные** альтернативы для небольших проектов вроде моего?

Answer (score 1):

В качестве запасного варианта - можно использовать Google Sheets. С формулой в ячейке `=GOOGLETRANSLATE(C3, "en", "es")`, он переведет значение из ячейки C3 с Английского на Испанский. Список поддерживаемых языков достаточно велик.

Comment: Автоперевод меня не интересует. Его должны осуществлять носители языка либо те, кто хорошо его знает.

Comment: @Artem врядли кто-то будет стараться забесплатно, но если найдете - дайте пожалуйста знать!

Comment: Всенепременно. Добровольцы всегда найдутся. К тому же, это некоммерческий проект. Думаю, в крайнем случае можно написать предложение присоединиться к переводу в виде issue на GitHub или в ReadMe.